# Is there any plugin which enables users to rate comments in thumbs up-down way?

Tags: plugins, rating

- The plugin should work with un-registered users also.
- Its not mandatory for plugin to add rating system to posts/pages. I need thumbs up-down rating system only for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i bet there are a lot but i have used
[Comment Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/) plugin before and its very good just for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've used GD Star Rating in the past. It works well. By default the ratings for posts and pages are turned on but you can disable this. You can also change the images that display for the thumb up/down easily

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/

Comment: GD Star Rating is nice, but its a bloatware. It has made me annoyed, so that I asked this question. Its thumbs down thing is that it creates boxes in functions.php which leads to design problems if your theme is complex. If a widget tries to fetch contents of a blog post, it gets internal codes of GD Star rating. Comment Rating plugin doesn't throw such type of problems..

Comment: Interesting to note. I haven't used the plugin for a while, and I haven't used it solely for the comment rating feature. 

Thanks for the input.